# How to do HELM test in Rancher UI?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher, rancher-rke

We integrated HELM and Rancher together. We deploy our help charts using rancher UI, in which release engineer selects the charts, Update the values.yaml, and deploys them. This is as good as doing "helm install  ".
However, We are not able to achieve the helm test feature using the rancher UI. Hence can anybody give me some info on how exactly we do "helm test" using rancher UI?

Comment: I believe it can't at the moment, check is issue tracking about test integration, it's also on their milestone as well https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/28630

Comment: @ThatBuffDude ,,. Thanks, hope rancher will do it asap

Comment: I'm pretty sure they'll be glad to receive a PR as well ;)